# Ruby create images of equations (LaTeX)

Tags: ruby, latex, equation

I'm looking for a way to create (and view) images of equations in Ruby.

After doing some math inside my script I want to view the result (a polynomial, to be exact) as an image to a user. This doesn't necessarily need to be LaTeX but I guess it would be the easiest way.

Is there any gem or other way to turn a string with LaTeX equation into an image/pdf file?

Any googling only gave me results on how to do this in Rails app, what I need is pure Ruby.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After even more Googling around I came up with this gem [Calculus](https://github.com/avsej/calculus), and it does exactly what I've been looking for.

The Readme file is pretty self-explanatory, so I won't be copying this here.